# How to copy blob file to SAS URL in a Synapse pipeline

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I have a blob zip file in my storage account, I have a linked service and binary dataset to get the file as the source in a copy activity.  There is an outside service I call in a web activity that returns a writable SAS URL to a different storage account in this format.

```
https://foo.blob.core.windows.net/dmf/43de9fb6-3b96-4f47-b730-eb8de040859dblah.zip?sv=2014-02-14&sr=b&sig=0mgvh25htg45b5u4ty5E%2Bf0ahMwFkHVy3iTC2nh%2FIKw%3D&st=2022-08-13T02%3A19%3A33Z&se=2022-08-13T02%3A54%3A33Z&sp=rw
```

I tried adding a SAS azure blob linked service, I added a parameter for the uri on the LS, then added a dataset bound to the LS and also added a parameter for the uri, I pass the SAS uri dynamically all the way down to the linked service.  The copy fails each time with **The remote server returned an error: (403)**.  I have to be doing something wrong but not sure what it is.  I'd appreciate any input, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got same error:**

[image: Ref1]

To resolve the above 403 error, you need to enable it from `all network` option and also check whether the Storage blob data contributor was added or not. If not , Go to **Azure Storage Account** -> **Access control (IAM)** -> **+Add role assignment** as `Storage blob data contributor`.

[image: Ref2]

Now, its working.

[image: Ref3]

Comment: I like the answer, unfortunately I don't have the ability to change the settings on the storage account.  Looking for another route